# echo lines not redirecting into bash script properly?

Tags: bash, redirect, echo

I have to create a bash script  (mkbackup.sh) from another bash script using redirection and echo commands. The file is created in the correct location, however when I enter it on vi only the last line I inputted (fi) is in the file. I have changed the permission to grant rwx access, do you have any idea what's going on?

```
location=$(pwd)

echo "\"$location\"/\"$new_file\""
touch "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
chmod +rwx "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh

echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "#MYNAME" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "#MYID" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    cp -r ../backup/ ../src/*.*" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "fi" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    echo \"$1\"" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    given_file=\"$1\"" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    cp \"$given_file\" ../src/" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "fi" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    if [\" $1\" == \"-z\" ]; then" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        tar -cf \"$2\" ../src/*.*" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        cp \"$2\" ../backups/" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    else" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        tar -zcf \"$2\" ../src/*.*" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        cp \"$2\" ../backups/" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    fi" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "fi" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "if [ $# -eq 4 ]; then" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    if [\" $1\" == \"-z\" ]; then" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        tar -cf \"$2\" ../src/\"$4\"" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        cp \"$2\" ../backups/" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    else" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        tar -zcf \"$2\" ../src/\"$4\"" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "        cp \"$2\" ../backups/" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
echo "    fi" > "$location"/"$new_file"/backups/mkbackup.sh
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` truncates the target file, so that every line you write is overwriting whatever was previously in that file. You could use `>>` to *append* to the target file, but this whole thing would be cleaner using a single `cat` process to write to a file that you open *once*, as well as simplifying the quoting greatly.

```
target=$(pwd)/$new_file/backups/mkbackup.sh

cat <<EOF > "$target"
#!/bin/bash
#MYNAME
#MYID
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    cp -r ../backup/ ../src/*.*
fi
...
EOF
```